# Databinding: Using a comma-separated list of values from XML in XDocument query

Tags: windows-phone-7

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am new to WP7 development (and C# in general).

I have an XML file that looks like this:

`<sessions>`

`<session id="305">`

`<startdatetime>2012-09-12 09:30:00</startdatetime>`

`<enddatetime>2012-09-12 10:30:00</enddatetime>`

`<name>TEST</name>`

`<description>[text]</description>`

`<venueID>19</venueID>`

`<speakerID>1764,2077,2361</speakerID>`

`</session>`

`<session> ... </session>`

`<session> ... </session>`

etc.`

`</sessions>`

Later in the XML there are nodes for venues and speakers, I can pull the venue out fine using

`var venuedata = from query in loadedData.Descendants("venues").Descendants("venue")`

`where query.Attribute("id").Value == session.venueID`

`select new Venue`

`{`

`[stuff]`

`};`

`[etc]`

But how do I do the same thing when the XML contains a comma-seperated list like the speakers in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string.Split to extract the comma-separated value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

```
select new Venue
{
    Speakers = query.Element("speakerID").Value.Split(',').ToList(),
    [stuff]
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with this:                 

`List<string> speakers = session.speakerID.Split(',').ToList();`

`var speakerdata = from query in loadedData.Descendants("speaker") where speakers.Contains(query.Attribute("id").Value)`